# Динамическое изменение даты в python

Tags: python, datetime

Пишу калькулятор денег или калорий, который должен подсчитать их сегодня (если введённая дата не совпадает с сегодняшней, подсчет не ведется). Столкнулся с проблемой, что при использовании `datetime.today()` он перестанет работать, если калькулятор будет работать больше дня. Значение перестанет быть актуальным. Как сделать так, что бы дата автоматически обновлялась всегда?

```
def __init__(self, limit):
    self.limit = limit
    self.records = []
    'self.today = dt.datetime.today()'
    self.remainder = self.limit - self.get_today_stats()

def add_record(self, record):
    self.records.append(record)

def get_today_stats(self):
    amount_of_money_or_calories = 0
    for copy_of_the_record in self.records:
        if self.today == copy_of_the_record.date:
            amount_of_money_or_calories += copy_of_the_record.amount
    return amount_of_money_or_calories
```

Comment: обновлять дату в начале функции

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать today вычисляемым свойством

```
def __init__(self, limit):
    self.limit = limit
    self.records = []
    #'self.today = dt.datetime.today()'
    self.remainder = self.limit - self.get_today_stats()

@property
def today(self):
    return dt.datetime.today()

def add_record(self, record):
    self.records.append(record)

def get_today_stats(self):
    amount_of_money_or_calories = 0
    for copy_of_the_record in self.records:
        if self.today == copy_of_the_record.date:
            amount_of_money_or_calories += copy_of_the_record.amount
    return amount_of_money_or_calories
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему получение текущей даты не перенести сразу в `get_today_stats`? Так на каждую проверку будете иметь текущую дату.

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.records = []
        self.remainder = self.limit - self.get_today_stats()

    def add_record(self, record):
        self.records.append(record)

    def get_today_stats(self):
        today = dt.datetime.today()
        amount_of_money_or_calories = 0
        for copy_of_the_record in self.records:
            if today == copy_of_the_record.date:
                amount_of_money_or_calories += copy_of_the_record.amount
        return amount_of_money_or_calories
```